# How define version of sub plugins that are executed by maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When I use the maven-release-plugin and run it then I see several warning messages:

```
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for li.pitschmann:knx-core:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.1:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 113, column 19
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.1:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 125, column 19
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.1:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 137, column 19
```

How can I set the version of 'maven-source-plugin', 'maven-javadoc-plugin' and 'maven-deploy-plugin' although I do **not have those defined** in my `pom.xml` file. It looks like those three plugins are invoked by 'maven-release-plugin'. To define the version of those three plugins (which are invoked by maven-release-plugin) do I have to add and define them in `<pluginManagement>` explicitly or is there a way possible through maven-release-plugin?

It is for me a surprise that none complained about this issue; so I am worried if I am on wrong path. At least I could not find same issue in stackoverflow, issues reported here seems be only similar but have other error sources. Clarifications are appreciated!

Comment: Most all people already define all plugins within a pluginManagement block within the projects either directory or at least via parent ...that's the correct way to go...and define all plugins via pluginManagement in your projects. If you have more than one project it might be a good idea to create your own parent pom which defines those plugins only once...

Comment: that is what I thought ... but thank you for the clarification!